# Open a browser with authentication header

Tags: javascript

I want to know if it is possible to open a browser with header authentication by Javascript?

I can assign header to the request in Postman when calling API.

But I can't find if it is reasonable to expect browser can do the same thing?

If yes, any example to trigger the browser with authentication header?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can get the browser to load a page that runs JavaScript then you can execute follow-on API calls and attach headers to them.  There are a variety of frameworks available or you can use the ES6 Fetch API that runs fine in most modern browsers.

Ref Fetch Docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Ref Headers specifically for Fetch:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers

Users could use a local file on their machine which has the script to fetch the data... or you could have users hit an endpoint that requires no authentication and merely serves to host up the page that has the API calls, gathers their credentials and then requests the authenticated data from the protected endpoints.

```
const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.set('Authentication', 'basic <insert base64 encoded basic auth string>');

const url = 'https://www.example.com/api/content';

const requestObj = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'default'
};

const myRequest = new Request(url, requestObj);

fetch(myRequest)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(jsonObj => {
    //do stuff with whatever was returned in the json object
  });
```

If you have an older browser that doesn't support JavaScript at the ES6 version or later, then you can revert to the older XMLHttpRequest.

Ref XMLHttpRequest Docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

```
var url = 'https://www.example.com/api/content';
var getRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
getRequest.open('GET', url, false);
getRequest.setRequestHeader("Authentication", ''basic <insert base64 encoded basic auth string>'');
getRequest.send(null);
if (getRequest.status == 200){
  var textData = req.responseText;
  // do stuff with the response data
}
```

That is a VERY basic use case for XMLHttpRequest...  you should definitely read the docs on setting it up to use call back functions instead of operating synchronously as in the example above.   But this should give you enough detail to move forward

Comment: can you provide a solution for the plain javascript for testing? (since the platform is very old it doesn't contain es6 reformatter)

Comment: edited answer to include information on the older XMLHttpRequest methods that can still be used.  It was deprecated by ES6 Fetch.. but since you're using an older browser should be what you want to look at...